# React stale state in useEffect when using empty dependency array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm trying to read state after it's modified within useEffect hook. However since useEffect closes over availability being empty array, it's not updated at all causing infinite loop.
I'm intentionally using empty dependency array since I want this to happen only after
the first render, so including availability as dependency is not an option.

I need some way to read up-to-date value from availability but I don't know how to.

```
  const [ availability, setAvailability ] = useState([])

  const updateAvailability = (data, manufacturer) => {
    setAvailability(availability => {
      const copy = {...availability}
      copy[manufacturer] = data
      return copy
    })
  }

  const parseAvailability = products => { 
    products.forEach(product => {
      if (!availability[product.manufacturer]) { // availability is stale after updates
        updateAvailability({}, product.manufacturer) // notify that data is coming soon
        service.getAvailability(product.manufacturer).then(data => { // http request to fetch availability 
          updateAvailability(data, product.manufacturer)
        })
      }
    })
   }

  useEffect(() => {
    config.categories.forEach(category => {
      service.getCategory(category.name).then(data => {
        parseAvailability(data, availRef)
      })
    })
  },[])
```

Comment: use reducer instead. It is always better to use a reducer when the state depends on the previous one

Comment: I don't understand, `availability[product.manufacturer]` can't be stale because the initial state hasn't been updated yet, it's not even enqueued (i.e. call to `updateAvailability`). Perhaps you could talk through or describe more what you are trying to accomplish. What you ask, with the provided code, just simply isn't possible. You'll likely need a second effect to respond to the state update the initial mounting effect does.

Comment: @DrewReese the if statement is inside loop since products.forEach() is called. It's not stale at first but becomes stale after the loop has run a few times. I'm simply trying to fill the availability object with data when the page is rendered but only at first render.

Comment: Array.forEach is 100% synchronous, no new state should be available until the function has completely finished. If you are seeing anything before then, then I suspect you are mutating your state object, i.e. `copy[manufacturer] = data` possibly. Have you considered [Lazy Initialization](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state)?